# reluctant quantifier using oracle regexp

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a string `'''val1'',''val2'''` that I want to convert to `'upper(''val1''),upper(''val2'')'` ... so I decided to use `regex_replace` ..... the problem is that I am not able to create a reluctant pattern .... the following pattern `regexp_replace('''val1'',''val2''','(''.*'')','upper(\1)')` is greedy and hence produces `'upper(''val1'',''val2'')'` ... any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to RegexBuddy, normal lazy quantifiers should work:

```
regexp_replace('''val1'',''val2''','(''.*?'')','upper(\1)')
```